# How To Filter a Dataframe based on Category Counts

Tags: r, filtering

How do I subset a dataframe so that only rows that contain columns that have a value that shows up a certain amount of times in other rows are included.

For example, if I have a column labeled Food, how would I filter out all rows that have a food that shows up less than 5 times in the whole dataframe?

Comment: I predict a solution will involve `table` and `%in%`.

Comment: @Joran: Ya, first thing I did was make a table, just wasn't sure how to connect that as a way to filter the dataframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(50),y=sample(letters,50,replace = TRUE))
dat[dat$y %in% names(table(dat$y))[table(dat$y) > 2],]
```

That selects all rows that contain a letter that appears more than twice.

Comment: Did you just predict your own answer? And does that count as true foresight? I'll upvote anyway, because your answer is simple and works.

Comment: @Seth - I'm waiting to get (back) on a plane, so I started with a comment, thinking I wouldn't have time for more. But then it seemed I had a few minutes, so I wrote the answer...at the moment I predict that I will have a very long day in airports. :(

Comment: Works, only caveat in my case (which I didn't state) was that since this is a factor, the boxplot still shows all of the levels along the X axis, instead of just the ones with values.

Comment: droplevels() should address that.

Comment: Ah, that can be fixed with `drop=T`

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach (probably cleaner) using `plyr`.

```
ddply(dat, .(y), subset, length(x) > 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of `ave` for problems like this.  Using the example data from @joran's answer:

```
set.seed(21)
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(50), y=sample(letters,50,replace=TRUE))
foo <- dat[dat$y %in% names(table(dat$y))[table(dat$y) > 2],]
bar <- subset(dat, ave(rep(1,nrow(dat)), dat$y, FUN=sum) > 2)
identical(foo,bar)
# [1] TRUE
```