# How do I filter a pandas DataFrame based on value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, dataframe

I'm working in Python with a pandas DataFrame of video games, each with a genre. I'm trying to remove any video game with a genre that appears less than some number of times in the DataFrame, but I have no clue how to go about this. I did find [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796569/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-based-on-category-counts) that seems to be related, but I can't decipher the solution at all (possibly because I've never heard of R and my memory of functional programming is rusty at best).

Help?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use [groupby filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  5  6

In [13]: df.groupby("A").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[13]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
```

I recommend reading the [split-combine-section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration).

Comment: And we can even group by MultiIndex level: groupby(level=...). Exactly what i've needed

Comment: this didn't work for me - I got the following error, not sure what to make of it:  "filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool" @Andy Hayden

Answer (score 42):

Solutions with better performance should be [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` for count per groups to Series with same size like original `df`, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby("A")['A'].transform('size') > 1]
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df[df['A'].map(df['A'].value_counts()) > 1]
```

Comment: For what it's worth regarding performance, I ran the `Series.map` solution here against the `groupby.filter` solution above through `%%timeit` with the following results (on a dataframe of mostly JSON string data, grouping on a string ID column):
`Series map: 2.34 ms ± 254 µs per loop`, `Groupby.filter: 269 ms ± 41.3 ms per loop`. So the `Series.map` solution is much faster

Comment: what is the group by formed by multiple columns?

Answer (score 5):

@jezael solution works very well, Here is a different approach to filter based on values count :

For example, if the dataset is :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,3,1,6], 'b': [11,2,33,4,55,6]})
```

Convert and save the count as a dictionary

```
ount_freq = dict(df['a'].value_counts())
```

Create a new column and copy the target column, map the dictionary with newly created column

```
df['count_freq'] = df['a']
df['count_freq'] = df['count_freq'].map(count_freq)
```

Now we have a new column with count freq, you can now define a threshold and filter easily with this column.

```
df[df.count_freq>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionlly, in case one wants to filter and have 'count' column:

```
attr = 'A'
limit = 10
df2 = df.groupby(attr)[attr].agg(count='count')
df2 = df2.loc[df2['count'] > limit].reset_index()
print(df2)

#outputs rows with grouped 'A' count > 10 and columns ==> index, count, A
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to this party but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_you_have.groupby(['IdA', 'SomeOtherA'])['theA_you_want_to_count'].count())
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This is how you create a new dataframe and then just filter it...

```
df[df['A']>100]
```