# Re-categorize a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories, dummy-variable

I am trying to build a simple classification model for my data stored in the pandas dataframe `train`. To make this model more efficient, I created a list of column names of columns I know to store categorical data, called `category_cols`. I categorize these columns as follows:

```
# Define the lambda function: categorize_label
categorize_label = lambda x: x.astype('category')

# Convert train[category_cols] to a categorical type
train[category_cols] = train[category_cols].apply(categorize_label, axis=0)
```

My target variable, `material`, is categorical, and has 64 unique labels it can be assigned to. However, some of these labels only appear once in `train`, which is too few to train the model well. So I'd like to **filter** any observations in `train` that have these rare material labels. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836836/how-do-i-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-value-counts) provided a useful groupby+filter combination:

```
print('Num rows: {}'.format(train.shape[0]))
print('Material labels: {}'.format(len(train['material'].unique())))

min_count = 5
filtered = train.groupby('material').filter(lambda x: len(x) > min_count)
print('Num rows: {}'.format(filtered.shape[0]))
print('Material labels: {}'.format(len(filtered['material'].unique())))
----------------------
Num rows: 19999
Material labels: 64
Num rows: 19963
Material labels: 45
```

This works great in that it does filter the observations with rare material labels. However, something under the hood in the `category` type seems to maintain all the previous values for `material` even after they've been filtered. This becomes a problem when trying to create dummy variables, and happens even if I try to rerun my same categorize method:

```
filtered[category_cols] = filtered[category_cols].apply(categorize_label, axis=0)
print(pd.get_dummies(train['material']).shape)
print(pd.get_dummies(filtered['material']).shape)
----------------------
(19999, 64)
(19963, 64)
```

I would have expected the shape of the filtered dummies to be (19963, 45). However, `pd.get_dummies` includes columns for labels that have no appearances in `filtered`. I assume this has something to do with how the `category` type works. If so, could someone please explain how to **re-categorize** a column? Or if that is not possible, how to get rid of the unnecessary columns in the filtered dummies?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37425961) ?

Comment: Perfect. Trying to accomplish the reverse, but reindexing is the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`category.cat.remove_unused_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html):

#### Usage

```
df['category'].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': list('aabbccd'),
                   'value': [1] * 7})
print(df)

  label  value
0     a      1
1     a      1
2     b      1
3     b      1
4     c      1
5     c      1
6     d      1
```

Lets set `label` as type category

```
df['label'] = df.label.astype('category')
print(df.label)

0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
4    c
5    c
6    d
Name: label, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [a, b, c, d]
```

Filter `DataFrame` to remove `label` `d`

```
df = df[df.label.ne('d')]
print(df)

  label  value
0     a      1
1     a      1
2     b      1
3     b      1
4     c      1
5     c      1
```

Remove unused_categories

```
df.label.cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
print(df.label)

0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
4    c
5    c
Name: label, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Selected because it specifically addresses the "re-categorization" questions. @jezrael's answer also works but more addresses the downstream problem of eliminating dummy matrix columns.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425961/dummy-variables-when-not-all-categories-are-present), this can be solved via reindexing and transposing the dummy dataframe:

```
labels = filtered['material'].unique()

dummies = pd.get_dummies(filtered['material'])
dummies = dummies.T.reindex(labels).T
print(dummies.shape)
----------------------
(19963, 45)
```

Comment: better `dummies = dummies.reindex(labels,axis=1)`