# Pandas, remove duplicates by column which duplicate N times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['file1','file1','file1','file1','file2','file3','file4','file4','file4','file4'],
    'text': ['Text1','Text2','Text3','Text4','Text5','Text6','Text7','Text8','Text9','Text10'],
})
```

I need to remove rows which 'file' repeat 4 time, so in this example i need to remove rows where file = file1 and file4

Comment: You are looking for this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836836/how-do-i-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-value-counts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get count of values per groups, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('file')['file'].transform('size') != 4]
```

Explanation: For using `transform` is necessary specify some column after `groupby` for counts - if use `size` it working same if use any column of `DataFrame` and it return new column (`Series`) with same size like original DataFrame filled by counts:

```
print (df.groupby('file')['file'].transform('size'))
0    4
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    1
5    1
6    4
7    4
8    4
9    4
Name: file, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) - performance should be slowier if large data:

```
df1 = df.groupby('file').filter(lambda x: len(x) != 4)
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df[df['file'].map(df['file'].value_counts()) != 4]
```

---

```
print (df)
    file   text
4  file2  Text5
5  file3  Text6
```

Comment: Can you explain for a little first variant, please, how this works, especially ('file)['file']?

Comment: @Contra111 - give me a sec, explanation will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` with `transform`:

```
df[df.groupby('file').text.transform('size').ne(4)]

   file   text
4  file2  Text5
5  file3  Text6
```