# Filter dataframe based on value_counts of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `data` which i need to filter based on other dataframe/Series value_counts which has been produced from `data` dataframe `Tags` column containing like list of string `['python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm']` using `pd.DataFrame(data.Tags.values.tolist()).stack().value_counts()` and this returns like this,

```
python                  20906
javascript              16692
java                    11324
c#                       8358
android                  7865
                        ...  
mysql-5.5                   1
asp-net-core                1
rxdatasources               1
background-sync             1
forwarding-reference        1
Length: 23633, dtype: int64
```

And I need to filter the `data` dataframe to remove Tags with `count >2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836836/how-do-i-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-value-counts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I filter a pandas DataFrame based on value counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836836/how-do-i-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-value-counts)

Comment: it is not related to my question. Pls read the question carefully. The question you are referring me is about the same dataframe and I am asking about `value_count` based on other dataframe. And pls open the question.

Comment: then please read how to ask a question and show a MRE, and all ur data

Comment: Can you pls open the question so that other may be able to answer?