# filter the dataframe using a condition in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

This might be a repeated question, but I couldn't get the answers of the other question.

I've a sample dataframe1

```
city       date        user         manager         mobile
LA      2021-03-01      XYZ          ABC            123456
LA      2021-03-02      XYZ          ABC            123456
LA      2021-03-03      XYZ          ABC            123456
FL      2021-03-01      DEF          MNO            099876
FL      2021-03-01      DEF          MNO            099867
TX      2021-03-01      KLM          PQR            9988887
```

How do I filter the df in order to get the data of `user` whose count is more than 1 in the df.
As the count of XYZ and DEF exceeds 1, the rows of that users should be filtered out.

Desired result

```
city       date        user         manager         mobile
LA      2021-03-01      XYZ          ABC            123456
LA      2021-03-02      XYZ          ABC            123456
LA      2021-03-03      XYZ          ABC            123456
FL      2021-03-01      DEF          MNO            099876
FL      2021-03-01      DEF          MNO            099867
```

Comment: Need `df[df['user'].duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: How do I use the count condition in that? what if I want records of the users whose count is more than 2 in that df. So only `XYZ` records would be filtered out. Because the count of XYZ in the column is more than 2.

Comment: added to list of dupes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie to pandas. Could you explain me a bit more with a solution?

Comment: Sure, what is unclear?

Comment: If you are new, maybe first check [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html)

Comment: so Im tring this `xyz = pd.concat(print(g) for _, g in email_report.groupby("employee") if (g.shape[0]) > 2)`, to get the entire dataframe that satisfice my condition. But didnt work. So it as no objects to concat.

Comment: Do you see second dupe? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29836836/2901002)

Comment: Thank you. Got my explanation and answer.