# Filtering rows based on counts of a specific factor

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I was wondering if I have one column name 'site' and another named 'year', how would I only select sites with a minimum of 4 years? I have seen similar questions elsewhere (e.g. [How To Filter a Dataframe based on Category Counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796569/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-based-on-category-counts)) but I don't know how to select such filters based on another column. An example dataset:

```
Site <- as.data.frame(as.factor(rep(c("Site.A","Site.B","Site.C"), each =4)))
Year <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013,
                               2010,2010,2010,2010)))
Count <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 3*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))

df <- cbind(Site,Year,Count)
colnames(df) <- c("site","year","count")
```

I.e. Site C would be removed from this dataset because there is only data from 1 year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using library `dplyr`, you can do something like this (note your data has zero cases like this):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Site) %>% filter(n_distinct(Year) >= 4)
```

Alternatively, if you just want Sites with five rows in the data, you can do:

```
df %>% group_by(Site) %>% filter(n() >= 4)
```

Note, `n_distinct()` in filter can be very slow on massive data sets (known bug in `dplyr`). If you run into this problem, simply replace that part only by `length(unique(Year))` as in:

```
df %>% group_by(Site) %>% filter(length(unique(Year)) > = 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'site', `if` the `length` of `unique` elements in 'year' is greater than 3 (`uniqueN(year) >3`), we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(year)>3) .SD , by = site]
#     site year count
#1: Site.A 2010     2
#2: Site.A 2011     3
#3: Site.A 2012     7
#4: Site.A 2013     6
#5: Site.B 2010     4
#6: Site.B 2011     0
#7: Site.B 2012     5
#8: Site.B 2013     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is one site observation per year, try using `table`:

```
# get names of site obs with counts >= 4
keepers <- names(table(df$Site))[table(df$Site) >= 4]
# keep these
dfNew <- df[df$Site %in% keepers]
```

If there is more than one site observation per year, you have to perform a slight adjustment to the keepers line above:

```
# create table for readability
yearSiteCount <- table(unique(df[,c("Site", "Year")])$Site)
keepers <- names(yearSiteCount)[yearSiteCount >= 4]
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Thank you for this! In my actual dataset, there are multiple observations per year though (i.e. different seasons)

Comment: @James White OK. That's fixable